# How to disable perPage limitation in admin on rest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, webpack, admin-on-rest

I need to render a `<ReferenceManyField />`.

By default, it use a `perPage` of `25` limitation that can be increased.

Is there a way to turn off this limitation `eg: perPage={false}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually it depends both on your backend setup and restClient you use...

see restClient example : https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/49a616c93d1ee5ea0bfa3c5f7abea0bb29c8d01c/src/rest/simple.js
(convertRESTRequestToHTTP)

it is possible to override pagination query like :

```
const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
const { field, order } = params.sort;

let query = {
    sort: JSON.stringify([field, order]),
    filter: JSON.stringify(params.filter),
};
if (perPage > 0) {
    query.range = JSON.stringify([
           (page - 1) * perPage,
           page * perPage - 1,
    ]);
}
```

(of course paging query params depends on your backend, it is just a sample )

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. However, you may just pass a very large value or maybe `-1`. It's then up to your backend to handle it correctly

Answer (score -1):

I used `perPage={-1}` for `ReferenceInput` and it worked for me.